# Is it possible to kill Ulfric after joining the Stormcloaks?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I've been thinking if it's possible to join the Stormcloaks only to realize Ulfric's an ass and kill him after that at some point of the game (I know you can't just go and kill him at first because he's an important NPC for the main story quests).

I don't want to join the Empire and - in my mind - what would make sense in my character's storyline would be him joining the Stormcloaks at first (because of how the game starts and my character being a Nord and having escaped with Ralof), but later realizing how Ulfric is only after power and how his fight against the Empire might even benefit the Altmers by weakening both forces (Empire and Rebellion). His Talos talk is just an excuse for his actions, as I see it. I really don't like this guy (he's a crazy racist who would do anything for power), but I also don't like what the Empire has become.

Please note that I don't really want spoilers about the plot, I just want to know if it is possible to challenge Ulfric to one-on-one combat "in the Old Nord Way" or just take the Rebellion for myself by assassinating him.

Comment: I *really* wish that had been marked as a spoiler alert....

Comment: There's no spoilers in this post.

Comment: @Joe Hints to Ulfric's disposition regarding power and other races in Skyrim are given when talking with many other NPCs, so they're not quest-related. Still, I understand why you might want those things hidden with the >! spoiler tag.

Comment: @victoriah maybe not to you, but I haven't joined either side yet, so I was unaware he was power hungry. Not really a spoiler, and it isn't a bg deal, but it is something I didn't know and would have rather figured that out by playing the game. :)

Comment: @Thaumajig true, but there are some who praise him as well. I always thought it depended what side the NPC was on. Guess I was wrong.

Comment: @Joe No, you're correct. Both sides have their admirable features, as well as several flaws that their opponents hold against them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have completed the Stormcloaks questline.

I headed over to Windhelm to see Ulfric, in the name of science. When you talk to him there's no option to challenge him to a duel or anything like that - he just tells you that you've done enough for now.

I tried attacking him, but he is like other "important" characters and cannot be killed. He just wussed out and fell to the floor instead.

There is one way that you can switch to Imperials halfway through the questline. I know that you don't want to support the Imperials, but it's the only option if you don't want to support Ulfric, unless you decide not to complete the quest chain at all.

> After you retrieve the Jagged Crown, instead of taking it to Ulfric you can take it to General Tullius in order to join the Imperials.

Comment: Thanks for testing this out and for your answer. I guess I'll just try to remain neutral for as long as I can as I progress through the main story.

Comment: It is possible to beat the game without picking a side in the civil war, there is just a change in one of the quests.

Answer (score 6):

Ulfric is an [Essential NPC](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Essential_NPCs) as a member of the Stormcloaks and therefore can't be killed.

Comment: I miss the days of Morrowind where you could kill an essential NPC and the game would just tell you that you've doomed everyone. :D

Comment: @aviangentile yeah you're right.

Answer (score 1):

I realize you're not asking about mods... but...

The exact thing you're asking for is possible with the Mod "Become High King of Skyrim".

And I quote:

> 3. ANY of the following:
>
> - Kill Ulfric or have him assassinated
> - Kill Elisif or have her assassinated

This mod is available, of course, on Nexus:

https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/41087

AND, it's also available on Bethesda for both the PC and XBox One (Sorry PS4 people... no luck.)

- PC:  https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/3205587
- XBox One V1: https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/3205625
- XBox One V2:  https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/4057214